# Trouble reading image OpenCV

Tags: c++, visual-studio, opencv, visual-studio-2013

I'm following the tutorial [here](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/introduction/windows_visual_studio_Opencv/windows_visual_studio_Opencv.html) for setting up OpenCV with Visual Studio (I have 2013 Community edition and OpenCV 2.4.10).

I have the following folder structure:

```
OpenCVTest

    -OpenCVTest.sln
    +x64
        +Debug
            - opencv_core2410d.dll
            - opencv_highgui2410d.dll
            - OpenCVTest.exe
            - OpenCVTest.ilk
            - OpenCVTest.pdb
            - feck.png
```

And my source:

```
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include <iostream>

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    if (argc != 2)
    {
        cout << " Usage: display_image ImageToLoadAndDisplay" << endl;
        return -1;
    }

    Mat image;
    image = imread(argv[1], IMREAD_COLOR); // Read the file

    if (!image.data) // Check for invalid input
    {
        cout << "Could not open or find the image" << std::endl;
        return -1;
    }

    namedWindow("Display window", WINDOW_AUTOSIZE); // Create a window for display.
    imshow("Display window", image); // Show our image inside it.

    waitKey(0); // Wait for a keystroke in the window
    return 0;
}
```

When I run this in VS or on the command line, I get the following error:

```
C:\Users\mr\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\OpenCVTest\x64\Debug>OpenCVTest.exe feck.png
Could not open or find the image
```

Anybody know why this might be happening?

**Update**

I have tried giving the full path:

```
image = imread("C:\Users\mr\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\OpenCVTest\feck.png", IMREAD_COLOR); // Read the file
```

and placing the image at the same level as the .sln file, still no luck.

Comment: can you try to provide absolute path, like `"C:/Users/mr/Documents/Visual Studio 2013/Projects/OpenCVTest/x64/Debug/feck.png"`

Comment: check that `feck.png` is a valid `.png` image

Comment: check if fopen(argv[1], "r+") != null.

Comment: Use double-backslash in code: image = imread("C:\\Users\\mr\\Documents\\Visual Studio 2013\\Projects\\OpenCVTest\\feck.png", IMREAD_COLOR);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the tutorial [here](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/introduction/windows_visual_studio_Opencv/windows_visual_studio_Opencv.html#windows-visual-studio-how-to), under "The local method", it reads:

> Then you need to specify the libraries in which the linker should look
>   into. To do this go to the Linker ‣ Input and under the “Additional
>   Dependencies” entry add the name of all modules which you want to use:

```
opencv_core231d.lib
opencv_imgproc231d.lib
opencv_highgui231d.lib
opencv_ml231d.lib
opencv_video231d.lib
opencv_features2d231d.lib
opencv_calib3d231d.lib
opencv_objdetect231d.lib
opencv_contrib231d.lib
opencv_legacy231d.lib
opencv_flann231d.lib
```

I changed these from `opencv_core{version}d.lib` to `opencv_core{version}.lib` (not the debug library) and it seems to work okay now. I can step through the code in Visual Studio and the code appears to work.

Comment: It is very important with Visual Studio to use debug dlls in a release application or release dlls (unless the allocations are isolated and you do not use stl accross the dll boundry) in a debug application because you will have more than 1 independent heap were you can not allocate memory in 1 heap and free it in a second. This will lead to heap corruption and random looking crashes. The same goes for using dlls from a different version of Visual Studio.

Comment: I appreciate that there must be a good reason for using them, however I could not get it working with them. If you could suggest a working alternative, I would definitely use them instead of the release ones.

Answer (score 0):

Place your image in OpenCVTest folder like this:

> C:\Users\mr\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\OpenCVTest\OpenCVTest\feck.png

```
-OpenCVTest.sln
-OpenCVTest <- **HERE**
-ipch
+x64
    +Debug
        - opencv_core2410d.dll
        - opencv_highgui2410d.dll
        - OpenCVTest.exe
        - OpenCVTest.ilk
        - OpenCVTest.pdb
        - feck.png
```

Comment: Hey, that didn't do it unfortunately.

Comment: How do you set openCV on your Visual Studio? Make sure all openCV library path is correct in "Debug | x64" Property Manager since you are using 64 bit machine.